# Can I work with rails3 in Windows with NEtbeans IDE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I believe that rails 3 support for windows is not released yet. Can I use Netbeans IDE and start working with Rails 3 in windows operating system ?

Comment: Why would you believe it is not supported on Windows yet? Rails is fully cross-platform. Netbeans is also fully cross-platform. The important thing is to use ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.2 for Rails3, which you can download from rubyinstaller.org; or use jruby (which is included in Netbeans if i am not mistaken).

Comment: Please note that Netbeans is going to discontinue Rails support in the next version. http://mattslay.com/ruby-on-rails-support-discontinued-in-netbeans-ide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gem install rails
```

You can use Rails 3 on Windows fine. I'm not sure about the IDE support, it may be lagging but the framework itself is fine on Windows (7).

Answer (score 1):

I have been using rails 3 on my Windows 7 machine but though I am not sure of Netbeans, as I use JetBrains

Comment: Any pointers of where can I download and install rails 3 in my windows ? Any links ?

Comment: Try referring to these links 1) http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/2/5/rails-3-0-beta-release 2) http://oscardelben.com/install-rails-3 3) http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm . Hope it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has syntax highlighting for Rails, if that's what you are asking if rails3 works with Netbeans.